# UITextField to UIWebView Form?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

How can I set up a UITextField, so that when a user inputs data into that UITextField - that data will be input into the UIWebView form and be submitted?

Thanks!

Comment: How can u get the user data in UILabel

Comment: UILabel is not for input... Are you sure you are using this object?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Meant UITextField! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, one option could be, 
get input in UITextField, and then make HTML  like this:

```
<form>
<input type="text"  value=[TextField.text] > 
</form>
```

and load html string in UIWebView.

Comment: But one problem that I have is that I can't change the form html... :(